# Calling non-empty constructor when defining a member object within a header file

Tags: c++, syntax

I feel like this is a mere syntactical question, but I can't find a unique/succinct way to describe it so Google isn't helping.

Here is a code snippet to see what I am talking about. The part that is preventing compilation is pointed out in a comment.

Deck.h:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class Deck{
    int top;
    int cards[52];

    public:
     Deck();
     void shuffle();

    private:
        // the "(0,51)" on the following line is a syntax error
        // without it, compilation is fine
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,51);
        std::shuffle_order_engine<std::default_random_engine, 52> engine;
};
```

Deck.cpp:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

Deck::Deck(){}

void Deck::shuffle(){
    top = 0;
    int oldCards[52];
    std::copy_n(cards, 52, oldCards);
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        int random = distribution(engine);
        std::cout << "random= " << random << std::endl;
        cards[i] = oldCards[random];
    }
}
```

I need to have the `uniform_int_distribution` instantiated with the range 0 to 51 to shuffle the deck. I could declare it as a pointer and allocate it dynamically, but this seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Coming from experience in C, I am trying to learn to write good, idiomatic C++ code, so anything else you can point out is appreciated. Of course, the actual working of the shuffling will be debugged once I can get compilation.

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Use braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: It seems that is a C++11 feature unsupported in clang 3.0. Any other way?

Comment: Clang, while great, is not the "bleeding edge". Either live with its limitations or find a new compiler.

Comment: @TJMonk15, It kind of is. It's the only one with a complete C++11 implementation (including library), and even has C++14 complete already.

Comment: @chris No. Clang does not fully support C++11 (At this time.) Hard Stop! Either deal with this fact, or move on.

Comment: @TJMonk15 [I beg](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) [to differ](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

Comment: @TJMonk15, Which feature is not supported?

Comment: Looking at your links (barely), the following are not full supported: "Minimal support for garbage collection and reachability-based leak detection", "Extended integral types". Since neither of those have to do with your question, a bug report might well be in order. But I would wait to see if someone on this awesome site can help you before that.

Comment: A google search gives me http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html. This says that Clang 3.3 has all of C++11 plus some more in the newer standards.

Comment: @TJMonk15, And those two are marked N/A for a reason and accompanied with notes. C++11 does not require those changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use curly braces, or copy initialization syntax.

Alternatively you can initialize that member in each constructor's member init list.

For C++03 the latter is the only possibility.

---

Curly braces:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 0, 51 };
```

---

Copy initialization syntax (only available if the type is copyable or movable):

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution =
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>( 0, 51 );
```

---

Initialization in constructor member init list:

```
Deck::Deck()
    : distribution( 0, 51 )
{}
```

Comment: I am probably talking beyond my rights as a C++ newcomer: why are there three ways to do something (granted, there are differences)? Is one more idiomatic? I was thinking the constructor memory init list would be most common.

Comment: Also, this is all unnecessary if the constructor takes no arguments. The constructor is called (sometime, at least) just by declaring the object it seems. It seems like the C way would be that the memory is allocated to be used on demand, but the contents are undefined behavior until initialized (in this case, by calling an empty constructor).

Comment: @MichaelSmith: the constructor memory init list is the old C++03 way, but it suffers from forcing you into redundant specifications of the same, once for each constructor. in C++03 you could only avoid that redundancy by introducing a custom extra class for the purpose (that class could be a base class). C++11 added more sane DRY syntax, Don't Repeat Yourself syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. That makes more sense now. I think I will update my compiler and go for the newer methods.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 supports both parenthesis and braces when initializing members in a class declaration, eg:

```
class Deck
{
    ...   
    private:
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,51);
        ...
};
```

```
class Deck
{
    ...   
    private:
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{0,51};
        ...
};
```

For non-C++11 compilers, you have to use the **initializer list** of the containing class's constructor to provide values to class member constructors (a C++11 compiler silently translates the above code into this logic behind the scenes), eg:

```
class Deck
{
    ...   
    private:
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution; // <-- DO NOT try to invoke the constructor here!
        ...
};
```

```
Deck::Deck()
  : distribution(0,51) <-- invoke the constructor here instead!
{
}
```

Comment: re "You have to use the initializer list of the parent class's constructor to provide values to class members that do not have a default constructor", no one doesn't have to, and no, there is no parent class.

Comment: After the edit the "For non-C++11 compilers" qualification fixes the have to claim, but there's still the bit about parent class.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: yes, you do have to use the parent class constructor to initialize members who DO NOT have a default constructor. `uniform_int_distribution` does have a default constructor, so it is possible to declare/construct and then initialize it separately, though initializing at construction is better. And the parent class is `Deck` in this example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I replaced *parent* with *containing*, happy now?

Comment: oh, terminology. yes, "containing" is much better. "parent" is like "base" or "super".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: then I would have actually said *base* if I meant that :-p  oh well.

Comment: C++ calls for a *brace-or-equal-initializer* after the declarator. Parentheses [are not supported](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/465f8b56e4df2be0).

Comment: @chris: not according to [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519): "Notice that a class member initializer can consist of any valid initialization expression, whether that's the traditional equal sign, a pair of parentheses, or the new brace-init".  Or the examples in [this article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2628.html): `private: HashingFunction hash_algorithm("MD5"); std::string s("Constructor run");`

Comment: First of all, I typically trust Clang more than articles, but take a look at §9.2 [class.mem].

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Check out [this section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2628.html#konaissue) of the paper, introduced at the top with *This goal will not be reached completely, however, because to avoid parsing problems, we no longer propose to allow initializers of the “( expression-list )” form as explained below.*